# UserForm adding DatePicker to Monthview and populating ActiveCell with data

Tags: vba, excel, datepicker, monthcalendar

I am using a MonthView form in VBA that allows the user to right-click and select InsertDate and choose from the form the date which will then populate into the Active Cell.  This code is working fine.  The issue is I need to add the time as well (military) which will succeed the date (i.e. 04/23/2014 18:11).

I am using the DateTimePicker form in VBA and have added this to the form.  Now I have a monthview and a DT Picker that is custom formatted for HH:mm.  The code of the entire user form is listed below.  The other part of the code is in "ThisWorkbook" which simply builds the context menu button "Insert Date" and attaches calendar and a Module that shows the calendar. My question is in the Sub DTPicker.  I want the values of both the MonthView and the DTPicker to populate the active cell, using the format mentioned above.  Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance!!

```
`Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Unload Me
End Sub


Private Sub DTPicker1_CallbackKeyDown(ByVal KeyCode As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal CallbackField As String, CallbackDate As Date)
On Error Resume Next

??????


End Sub


Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
On Error Resume Next
    ActiveCell.value = DateClicked
    Unload Me
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Click()

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize1()
    If IsDate(ActiveCell.value) Then
        Me.MonthView1.value = ActiveCell
    Else
        Me.MonthView1.value = Now
    End If
End Sub



Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    With frmCalendar
        .Top = Application.Top + 340
        .Left = Application.Left + 345
    End With
End Sub`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure exactly where the date and the time picker will insert the values and how the values they return look like exactly, but you can try the below way to format into waat you need:

Set the value returned by the DT Picker to `a` variable, then

`b = Format(a, "m/d/yyyy HH:mm")`

Now write the value of `b` to the cell as required.

Hope that helps:)

**EDIT:**

What about this:

```
a = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1") ' value from MonthView
b = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1") ' value from Date Picker

c = Format(a + b, "m/d/yyyy HH:mm") ' combined value in the requested format.

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("D5").Value = c
```

[Screen http://im68.gulfup.com/b01sVD.png](http://im68.gulfup.com/b01sVD.png)

**EDIT 2:**

I have gone the through the video in the link that you have posted in the comments, and assuming you want to insert the current time along with the date selected you can update the below part of your code:

```
Private Sub MonthView1_DateClick(ByVal DateClicked As Date)
On Error Resume Next   
a = DateClicked
b = Time
c = Format(a + b, "m/d/yyyy HH:mm") ' combined value in the requested format.
ActiveCell.value = c
Unload Me
End Sub
```

This way when the user selects a date the current time is also added to it in the m/d/yyyy HH:mm format.

Let me know if this does it for you.

Comment: I cannot set the DT picker to that format because the DT picker is only used for the time.  I am using a MonthView for the date.  I am trying to define and initialize the DTPicker to grab the value that the user inputs, then essentially concatenate the MonthView value with the DTPicker Value into the Active Cell..make sense?

Comment: Give me a few minutes, I think I got it. I will be editing my answer.

Comment: That is the right logic.  I cannot have the other values in A1 or B1.  The value (m/d/yyyy HH:mm) needs to be placed in "H8", or what I have setup as the ActiveCell-- that is the only value that can exist from the code.

The issue is still with the user form.  I have the form setup right now, you right-click to access the form but it only works for the MonthView-- if you click on any date, it will insert it into the ActiveCell.  The Time counter is on the bottom and needs to be added to the date.  Maybe I need an Ok Command button at the bottom when both of these have been entered.

Comment: The above is just an illustration example, you can just set the value returned from the MonthView as `a` and the value from DT Picker `b` then use the above to merge them into `c` and you can write the value of `c` into any cell you like. Is it not working?

Comment: I need help on the code under the DatePicker.  What would you write in that subroutine?  If i can get that value that is inserted into a variable (HH:mm), then I will set the MonthView to a variable as well, and I guess in a seperate subroutine I will add the two together..?

Comment: Can you kindly upload a copy of your file and post a link so that I can have a look? Thanks.

Comment: I really can't. There are other scripts in the file that cannot be shared.  I have followed the tutorial here thought: http://www.familycomputerclub.com/pop-up-calendar-add-in.html
and simply want to add a DTPicker to the code and have it concatenate in the cell with the MonthView

Comment: I totally understand. Well in this case, can you then at least post a sample file with everything removed except the DT Picker & the MonthView forms so hopefully I can have a look at what is going wrong?

Comment: If you build out/read exactly what the link I sent says, that is what I have.

Comment: Your edit is getting there.  When you set b = Time it is grabbing the current time, not the time that is clicked.  If you watched the video, I have all of that.  But below the MonthView on the form I have added a DTPicker which has an up/down arrow and has the date modified as HH:mm so that the USER can select the date.  That is why I have a subroutine out there that needs editing that is directly associated with the Time selection.  Make sense?

Comment: I need both date and time in the m/d/yyyy/ HH:mm format, but I need the user to be able to select both of them and have them populate the active cell.  I am still fiddling with it to see what I can do, let me know if you know anything

Comment: I fixed it.  I just made the DTPicker Subroutine Public.  Then I set b = DTpicker1.value, and then kept C as is.  Thanks buddy!

Comment: if you will check out my new link, something seems to be up with the Monthview format.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24614063/monthview-and-dateclicker